# Program schedule

Tags: estimation, schedule

I inheritated a project on 2 September 2023 with Nov 20 2022 as the start date but no baseline schedule was created. 10 out 100 deliverables were completed as of 2 September 2023. Is it a good idea to include those deliverables in the new schedule?...this means my project start date will be Nov 20 2022.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE

Comment: What is the significance of the schedule for those past events? If there is some contractual or commercial significance, then that might be a reason to include them. Otherwise, people are probably more interested in what is coming than what is in the past.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of visibility and traceability, I would prefer to keep them in the project plan with their completion dates, as much as I can find out because it is not a new project; it is a project that started on 11/20/2022 and it is not good to see that the real action started in 09/02/2023. When a new project takes over your project, they will have lots of questions to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'd include them but wouldn't spend too much time finding out the dates that they were started or completed. My approach would be to put a milestone in at 2 September 2023 which relates to you becoming the new PM, and show the ten deliverables as starting in November 2022 and ending on 1 September 2023. This gives you a complete list of project deliverables, while making it clear that you were not responsible for them.

Answer (score 0):

New schedule implies the preceding schedule is no longer viable or credible. If some kind of summary is required regarding schedule performance and what was completed and when, you can accomplish this using a written report. Your new schedule ought to reflect going forward.